# iOS: Full Text Search

Tags: ios, xcode, full-text-search

My App is parsing the results of the search right after the user typed it into the UISearchBar. Everything works fine. But now I'd like to search the full text. The results are in my NSMutableArray, but not displayed. I think the problem is this code:

```
NSRange nameRange = [SDPE.title rangeOfString:self.searchBar.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

What can I do?

Comment: You may want to try using an `NSPredicate` instead. You can do more complex filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to Jack Lawrence good advice I found the perfect Answer:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope
 {
     NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                     searchText];

    searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
 }
```

Source: http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
  searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
  if([self.filteredListContent count]>0)
  {
    [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.
  }

  for (int cnt = 0; cnt< [self.listContent count];cnt++)
  {
    NSRange range = [[[self.listContent objectAtIndex:cnt]lowercaseString]  rangeOfString :[searchText lowercaseString]];

    if(range.length>0)
    {
        [self.filteredListContent addObject:[self.listContent objectAtIndex:cnt]];
    }
    self.blSearchBarClicked = TRUE;
    [self.tbViewSearch reloadData];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Prince. I removed the options: and added the lowercaseString instead. It's filtering my results like before..